# Create date from year, month and day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

Does Oracle have a builtin function to create a date from its individual components (year, month and day) that just returns null on missing data?

I'm aware of `TO_DATE()` but I need to compose a string first and neither the `||` operator nor the `CONCAT()` function make it easy to handle missing data:

```
-- my_year NUMBER(4,0) NULL
SELECT TO_DATE(my_year || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS my_date
FROM my_table;
```

Whenever `my_year` is `NULL` we end up with `TO_DATE('-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` and:

```
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

Comment: What is the value of `my_year`?

Comment: @AlexK. - Anything that fits into a `my_year NUMBER(4,0) NULL` column, including `NULL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example, you can use `case`:

```
select (case when my_year is not null and my_year <> 0 and
                  my_year between -4713 and 9999
             then TO_DATE(my_year || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        end)
```

Unfortunately, Oracle does not have a method of doing the conversion, if possible, and otherwise returning NULL.  SQL Server recently introduced `try_convert()` for this purpose.

One option is to write your own function with an exception handler for the failed conversion.  The exception handler would simply return `NULL` for a bad format.

Comment: Thank you. I guess my fears were true :)

Answer (score 4):

I've eventually composed a user-defined function to encapsulate the logic. It returns a date from its individual components or `NULL` if the date is not valid:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TRY_TO_DATE (
    V_YEAR IN NUMBER,
    V_MONTH IN NUMBER,
    V_DAY IN NUMBER
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
    RETURN TO_DATE(LPAD(V_YEAR, 4, '0') || LPAD(V_MONTH, 2, '0') || LPAD(V_DAY, 2, '0'), 'YYYYMMDD');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN NULL;
END TRY_TO_DATE;
/
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sqP-t3-p)

Comment: I might miss something, or the `-` characters should be there, shouldn't it? Something like `LPAD(...) || '-' || LPAD(...)`.

Comment: @csisy Thanks for the heads up. Parser is lenient enough, but it was indeed wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use year zero with `to_date('0000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`, but oddly you can with a date literal `date '0000-01-01'`. On its own that becomes year -1, but you can use it calculations; and you can add an interval too which can be based on your numeric value, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE '0000-01-01' + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(my_year, 'YEAR') AS my_date
FROM my_table;
```

The [`numtoyminterval` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions118.htm) returns null if the argument is null, and adding that to a fixed date also gives you null:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD';

select date '0000-01-01' + numtoyminterval(null, 'YEAR') from dual;

DATE'0000-01-01'+NUMTOYMINTERVAL(NULL,'YEAR')
---------------------------------------------


select date '0000-01-01' + numtoyminterval(2015, 'YEAR') from dual;

DATE'0000-01-01'+NUMTOYMINTERVAL(2015,'YEAR')
---------------------------------------------
 2015-01-01                                  

select date '0000-01-01' + numtoyminterval(9999, 'YEAR') from dual;

DATE'0000-01-01'+NUMTOYMINTERVAL(9999,'YEAR')
---------------------------------------------
 9999-01-01                                  

select date '0000-01-01' + numtoyminterval(-4712, 'YEAR') from dual;

DATE'0000-01-01'+NUMTOYMINTERVAL(-4712,'YEAR')
----------------------------------------------
-4712-01-01
```

It isn't foolproof; it will still error if you try to go before -4713:

```
select date '0000-01-01' + numtoyminterval(-4713, 'YEAR') from dual;

SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
...
```

Though you can avoid that with a check constraint on the column. And because of the silent translation of year 0 to -1, you get the same answer if your `my_year` value is 0 or -1:

```
select date '0000-01-01' + numtoyminterval(0, 'YEAR') from dual;

DATE'0000-01-01'+NUMTOYMINTERVAL(0,'YEAR')
------------------------------------------
-0001-01-01                               

select date '0000-01-01' + numtoyminterval(-1, 'YEAR') from dual;

DATE'0000-01-01'+NUMTOYMINTERVAL(-1,'YEAR')
-------------------------------------------
-0001-01-01
```

Gordon Linoff's case approach is more robust, but this might work if you're only really dealing with 'sane' positive years. And if not, it's mildly interesting...

Comment: There goes my answer! I was going to suggest wrapping in a user-defined function with y2m and d2s interval parameters as well; but it's all the same thang.

Comment: Yes, wasn't sure if it would just be the year from the way the question starts, but it's extandable as you say. And possibly worth wrapping in a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
where my_year > 0
```

This will just return rows where it's possible to create a date.  Ignoring rows with null or with a value of 0. If you have some values not in the range -4713 and +9999, you should of course exclude those in the where clause too.

Comment: I still need to use the row. It isn't difficult to filter out "bad" values from the calculation (see Gordon's answer) but the syntax is too verbose.