# Change the year in a date inside a case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I need to structure a `WHERE` clause in this way:

- If the month of `SysDate` is *December*, the desired value should be the `01/12 00:00:00` (1st December at midnight) and the year should be the *current year*
- If the month of `SysDate` is any *other month*, the desired value should be the `01/12 00:00:00` (1st December at midnight), **BUT** the year should be the *previous year*

The column in question is of `DATE` type.

For example,

- If I will run the query on `14 December 2019`, the result should be `01/12/2019 00:00:00`
- If the query is run today (`14 January 2019`) the result should be `01/12/2018 00:00:00`.

Comment: What code have you tried so far ? and what is not working in that .

Comment: @SudiptaMondal I didn't try any code because I don't know how to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119710/how-do-i-get-the-current-year-using-sql-on-oracle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538180/create-date-from-year-month-and-day

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

- In case of December all we should do is to `trunc`ate up to the `'month'`: `14 Dec 2017 15:56:45.666` -> `1 Dec 2017`
- If we have other month, we can get `1 Jan` with a help of `trunc` up to the `'year'` and *subtract* one month: `14 Apr 2015 23:40:01.583` -> `1 Jan 2015` -> `1 Dec 2014`

**Demo Query:**

```
select case 
         when extract(month from MyDate) = 12 then
           -- December 
           trunc(MyDate, 'Month')
         else
           -- All the other months  
           add_months(trunc(MyDate, 'Year'), -1)
       end as MyModifiedDate
  from MyTable
```

If you want to put it in `where` with `SysDate`:

```
select ...
  from MyTable
 where ...
       case 
         when extract(month from SysDate) = 12 then
           trunc(SysDate, 'Month')
         else
           add_months(trunc(SysDate, 'Year'), -1)
         end = /*TODO: Put the right condition here */
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach where I only look at the year when compairing the date column (`someDate`in my example) with sysdate

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE CASE  
   WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) = 12 AND ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) + 1) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM someDate)) THEN 1
   WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) <> 12 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM someDate) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `trunc()` to truncate the date to the 1st Jan of that year.

By adding a month to the date and then truncating, you mimic dates in December actually being January. So when you truncate it to the year, it'll pick up the year from the next year. Then you need to subtract a month to get the date back to the correct month.

E.g.:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT to_date('01/11/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + LEVEL -1 dt
               FROM   dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 500)
SELECT dt,
       add_months(TRUNC(add_months(dt, + 1), 'yyyy'), -1) yr
FROM   dates
ORDER BY dt;


DT          YR
----------- -----------
01/11/2017  01/12/2016
02/11/2017  01/12/2016
03/11/2017  01/12/2016
<snip>
29/11/2017  01/12/2016
30/11/2017  01/12/2016
-- year change here
01/12/2017  01/12/2017
02/12/2017  01/12/2017
03/12/2017  01/12/2017
<snip>
29/12/2017  01/12/2017
30/12/2017  01/12/2017
31/12/2017  01/12/2017
01/01/2018  01/12/2017
02/01/2018  01/12/2017
03/01/2018  01/12/2017
04/01/2018  01/12/2017
05/01/2018  01/12/2017
06/01/2018  01/12/2017
<snip>
26/11/2018  01/12/2017
27/11/2018  01/12/2017
28/11/2018  01/12/2017
29/11/2018  01/12/2017
30/11/2018  01/12/2017
-- year change here
01/12/2018  01/12/2018
02/12/2018  01/12/2018
03/12/2018  01/12/2018
04/12/2018  01/12/2018
05/12/2018  01/12/2018
06/12/2018  01/12/2018
<snip>
26/12/2018  01/12/2018
27/12/2018  01/12/2018
28/12/2018  01/12/2018
29/12/2018  01/12/2018
30/12/2018  01/12/2018
31/12/2018  01/12/2018
01/01/2019  01/12/2018
02/01/2019  01/12/2018
03/01/2019  01/12/2018
04/01/2019  01/12/2018
<snip>
```