# Determine if date is valid in a trigger statement

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm pulling in data from a 3rd party vendor as a CSV. THe CSV contains date fields that are strings. On insert I have triggers set to convert the string date fields to a valid date and store into an additional field in the table. Some of the date strings contain words like "NONE" rather then a valid date string so my trigger is failing with these records. Is there a way that I can have the trigger first look to see if its a valid date string then if it is do the conversion else leave it null?

Current trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER tr_vendor_contract
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON WOODBURN_ALL
    FOR EACH ROW       
    BEGIN 
        :NEW.VENDORCONTRACT := TO_DATE(:NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    END;
```

I've tried changing the trigger to:

```
create or replace TRIGGER tr_vendor_contract
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON UTAHDDW.WOODBURN_ALL
    FOR EACH ROW       
    BEGIN 
        IF:NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING != 'NONE' THEN
        :NEW.VENDORCONTRACT := TO_DATE(:NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        END IF;
    END;
```

But then I still get an error on insert if the vendor_contract_string value = 'NONE'

ERROR:
`ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 ORA-06512: at "UTAHDDW.TR_VENDOR_CONTRACT"`

I've also tried :

```
create or replace TRIGGER tr_vendor_contract
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON UTAHDDW.WOODBURN_ALL
    FOR EACH ROW       
    BEGIN 
        IF :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING = 'NONE' THEN :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING := NULL;
        ELSIF :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING != 'NONE' THEN :NEW.VENDORCONTRACT := TO_DATE(:NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create date from year, month and day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64766303/13508)

Comment: No - the problem isn't formatting the date - as you can see in the OP, I'm doing that. The problem is that some dates come in as the string 'NONE' which oracle can not convert to a valid date. I need the trigger t skip an instances where the value = 'NONE'

Comment: The problem is that you don't get `EXCEPTION` triggered or that you don't want a function but inline code?

Comment: You don't specify what technique you are using to load this csv file, but it seems that a trigger is not really needed.  Why can't your logic be implemented in the loading procedure itself?

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12c you can use `DEFAULT value ON CONVERSION ERROR` in the `TO_DATE` function:

```sql
create or replace TRIGGER tr_vendor_contract
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON UTAHDDW.WOODBURN_ALL
    FOR EACH ROW       
    BEGIN
      :NEW.VENDORCONTRACT := TO_DATE(
        :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
        'YYYY-MM-DD'
      );
      IF UCASE(:NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING) := 'NONE' THEN
        :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING := NULL;
      END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue came down to capitalization. The following solution worked:

```
create or replace TRIGGER tr_vendor_contract
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON UTAHDDW.WOODBURN_ALL
    FOR EACH ROW       
    BEGIN 
        IF :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING = 'None' THEN :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING := NULL;
        ELSIF :NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING != 'None' THEN :NEW.VENDORCONTRACT := TO_DATE(:NEW.VENDOR_CONTRACT_STRING, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        END IF;
    END;
```

I understand this isn't a robust solution because its looking for a specific non-date string. Fortunately this works in this case. It would still be helpful to know if there is a way to test if a string is a valid date before setting it.